# How do I append only updated texts?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, streamwriter

I have a Winform control to write notes whose contents are periodically uploaded to the server.
I need to create a local file as a backup to save the contents of the notes.
When I type text into the notebox, the content remains in the note box and gets saved into the local text file. However, when I enter more texts to the note-box, the previous content as well as the new content gets appended to the local file. 
How do I make sure that only the recent content gets appended to the local file? If i clear the note-box content, no content gets logged on to the server.

```
 private void btnNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Note noteFrm = new Note();

            //set Note Text
            noteFrm.NoteText = _timeCard.NoteText;

            if (noteFrm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Save notes locally as well
                string path = @"C:\QB Notes\";
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                string projname = this._timeCard.Project.ProjectName.TrimEnd()+".txt";
                string fileloc = path + projname;

                // FileStream fs = null;
                 if (!File.Exists(fileloc))
                 {      
                     using (TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(fileloc))
                     {
                        // TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(fileloc);
                         txt.Write(noteFrm.NoteText + Environment.NewLine);
                        txt.Close();
                     }
                 }
                 else if (File.Exists(fileloc))
                 {
                     using (var txt = new StreamWriter(fileloc, true))
                     {
                        txt.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                        txt.Write(noteFrm.NoteText + Environment.NewLine);                  
                         txt.Close();
                     }
                 }
                //noteFrm.NoteText="";
                //get Note Text
                _timeCard.NoteText = noteFrm.NoteText;
                Utils.LogManager.write("New Note Text: " + noteFrm.NoteText);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Define "recent content".  Is it sufficient to remember the character index of the last character that was saved?  What if you go back and edit stuff that has already been saved?  Is it OK to just write the file in its entirety rather than append?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just overwrite the file when you save? What if they go back to fix a typo, for instance? Trying to manage all that would be a nightmare.

Comment: I guess it is okay to over write the entire file, but could you tell me how to read  and write from a particular index? @Wyck

Comment: @V_stack You can use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext) to add text to the end of a file. But you can't add text into the middle of a file without rewriting the entire file (you need to read the file, insert text, then replace the whole file)

Comment: The problem with over-writing the entire content is that, the application I am working on crashes a lot. And when it crashes, the data in the notes-box loses its last data entry, and if just add new data to it again without copying the contents from the local file to it first, i lose that data entry as its replacing the entire file. Im not sure if I am explaining this well. @Wyck

Comment: The unwritten portion of the string would be `noteFrm.NoteText.Substring(indexOfFirstUnwrittenCharacter)`  After writing that text to a file, you would update `indexOfFirstUnwrittenCharacter = noteFrm.NoteText.Length`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the file to always match what is in the text box, then I'd suggest that you replace your whole `if (!File.Exists(fileloc))` block with just this:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileloc, noteFrm.NoteText + Environment.NewLine);
```

That will create the file if needed, open the file, replace all the contents with what is in the text box, and close the file.

Comment: the reason this is the answer is because: lets say you put `hi` in the textbox and you save it. your file now says `hi`. then you add `hello`. the textbox now says `hi hello` so when you APPEND it tothe file, the file says `hi hi hello' because your adding it to the file. the method above will allow you to replace the text, and end up with `hi hello` instead of repeatedly adding it.

Comment: The problem with over-writing the entire content is that, the application I am working on crashes a lot. And when it crashes, the data in the notes-box loses its last data entry, and if just add new data to it again without copying the contents from the local file to it first, i lose that data entry as its replacing the entire file.

Comment: For example I enter "Hi" followed by "Hello". Now my local file has both "Hi" and "Hello", and now my app crashes. When i run my app going, my text box now contains only "Hi". So now i need to copy the contents of my local file which has both "Hi" and "Hello" and paste it back into my text box and continue writing to it. If I dont copy, and just continue writing to it, I lose the word "Hello" as my local file is also gonna be over written

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't trying to figure out why your application is crashing?

Comment: I still am trying to figure that part out, but until i figure out whats causing the problem, I am just trying to maintain a local copy.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't overwrite the whole file. You want the text file to match exactly what's in the note box, right?

Comment: " So now i need to copy the contents of my local file which has both "Hi" and "Hello" and paste it back into my text box and continue writing to it. " Yes, you will need to do it if your application keeps crashing and you want your text box and file to be in sync.

Comment: Is there anyway I can import the contents of the local file into my Notes text box at bootup? If my application crashes and y local file has all the notes, when i retsart my application, can I just import from the local file to the wincontrol?@GabrielLuci

Comment: Yes: [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext)